# Signup then login a user with Django

Tags: django, view, httprequest

I have a simple signup form (in signup.html)

```
<form action="adduser" method="post">
{% csrf_token %}
  Email Address: <input type="email" name="email" required autocomplete="on" placeholder="fr@star.com"/><br/>
  Username: <input type="text" name="username" maxlength=25 required placeholder="JoyfulSophia"/><br/>
  Password: <input type="password" name="password" maxlength=30 required placeholder="**********" /><br/>
  <br/>
  <input type="submit" value="Send" /> <input type="reset">
</form>
```

This redirects to the addUser view:

```
def adduser(request):
    u = User.objects.create_user(request.POST['username'], request.POST['email'], password=request.POST['password'])
    u.save()
    a = Accounts(user=u)
    p = Passwords(user=u)
    a.save()
    p.save()
    return HttpResponseRedirect(reverse('OmniCloud_App.views.profile', args=(u.id,)))
```

Here is the profile:

```
@login_required    
def profile(request, User_id):
    u = get_object_or_404(User, pk=User_id)
    a = get_object_or_404(Accounts, pk=User_id)
    return render_to_response('profile.html', context_instance=RequestContext(request))
```

So they wouldn't be signed in, but that's okay because we can send you over to /accounts/login?next=/7/ since they are user 7 (Problems Ahead!)

```
def login(request):
    username = request.POST['username']
    password = request.POST['password']
    user = auth.authenticate(username=username, password=password)
    if user is not None and user.is_active:
        auth.login(request, user)
        return HttpResponseRedirect("/account/profile/")
    else:
        return HttpResponseRedirect("/account/invalid/")
```

The request doesn't contain anything called username, but the one which was submitted to the addUser form does, so how can I shoot that bro over to login? I could have it parse the url (which contains the next=USER_ID) but that wouldn't work for someone that just types in base_url/login, and the user_id won't be part of the url forever. So what's a brother to do?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Post data exists only for one request. If you want to use it later you should save it somewhere else.

You could login the user right after registration, in `adduser` view, he just entered his username and password, he doesn't have to do it again.

And login view is a little off. This is just a "POST" part of the view. You need to check and see if it's GET request and if it is return template with form containing `username` and `password` fields and with target url that points to the same view. Something like this:

```
def login(request):
    if request.method == 'GET':
        return render_to_response('login.html', 
                                  { 'form': LoginForm() },
                                  context_instance=RequestContext(request))
    elif request.method == 'POST':
        form = LoginForm(request.POST)
        if form.is_valid():
            username = form.cleaned_data['username']
            password = form.cleaned_data['password']
            user = auth.authenticate(username=username, password=password)
            if user is not None and user.is_active:
                auth.login(request, user)
                return HttpResponseRedirect("/account/profile")
            else:
                return HttpResponseRedirect("/account/invalid/")
```

Where `login.html` is something like this:

```
{% extends "base_site.html" %}

{% block content %}
    <form method="post" target="{% url login_view %}">
    {% csrf_token %}
    {{ form.as_p }}
    <input type="submit" value="Login" />
    </form>
{% endblock content %}
```

Also, you could return user to the same login form if username and password didn't match and add some message!

This is just from the top of my head, didn't try it, but it should work!

Comment: I already have a login.html, so do I need to include the {form, LoginForm()... etc ?

Comment: It's not necessary to have LoginForm, you can type html yourself and then extract data from request.POST, but I would suggest to use it. I would use one for registration as well, it can make things easier. Also, if you do create one you will have to import it. According to view I wrote in answer form will be available in template as `form`, but you can change it.

Answer (score 0):

There is an extensible user-registration application for Django called [django-registration](http://pypi.python.org/pypi/django-registration/) that offers you a lot of functionality for creating and registering users. Setting it up is very simple, you can find a very good doc [here](http://docs.b-list.org/django-registration/0.8/quickstart.html)